# How to AutoIncrement ID

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to ask about auto increment id. like us001 to us002 in sign up textbox.

Here is my code so far.

```
namespace login
{
  public partial class SignUp : Form
  {
    public SignUp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SignUp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){          
       autogenerateid();
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Azis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\1801405462(OOD)\1801405462(OOD)\cake.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    string userid = "UserID";

    private void autogenerateid() {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Azis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\1801405462(OOD)\1801405462(OOD)\cake.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Count(UserID) from User", con);
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        i++;
        useridnumber.Text = userid + i.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: How `autogenerateid()` should be called?

Comment: What's wrong with `i++`?

Comment: It's a DB, why not just add the attribute to the column?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Manually incrementing is not an AutoIncrement - leave that job to the DB; rolling you own based on Count is going to fail eventually, encoding text with a number is also a bad idea

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to base the user id on the user count in the User table. When you delete users, you are going to duplicate ids.

Make sure the User table has an identity column and select [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185(v=sql.80).aspx) when inserting the new user into the table.

Answer (score 0):

You must define your column `identity` if you want it to be auto increment .**it doesn't need to do that manually in your code**

```
create MyTable 
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this property as true. Just Google

> ID identity visual studio

and you'll find a lot of similar ways to do the same thing.

[image: Set this property as true]